# Spring Boot security RequestRejectedException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, firewall

I got the following error with my Spring Boot application:

```
org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the header value "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; ГўВЂВ¦) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0" is not allowed.
    at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall$StrictFirewalledRequest.validateAllowedHeaderValue(StrictHttpFirewall.java:833) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar!/:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall$StrictFirewalledRequest.getHeader(StrictHttpFirewall.java:716) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar!/:6.0.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getHeader(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:82) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getHeader(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:82) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getHeader(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:82) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getHeader(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:82) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
```

How to configure Spring Security in order to avoid such errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `HttpFirewall` is `StrictHttpFirewall` which will by default reject header value that contains [ISO control characters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isISOControl(char)) and character that are not [defined](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isDefined(int)) :

You can try to configure the `HttpFirewall` to accept more relax header values by setting the corresponding predicate that satisfy your need by:

```java
public class Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
       StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
        
        //configure it the to Predicate that satisfy your need...
        firewall.setAllowedHeaderValues(xxxxx)
        web.httpFirewall(firewall);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error because a header contains an apostrophe (') character, which is normally plain ascii (U+0027), not in the control character range. The header is in latin-1 encoding, is there some reason why Spring could be interpreting it using another encoding or so?